# How to dynamically set the RowHeight of a ListView in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a ListView with Xamarin Forms. The RowHeight for each of the list element may very dynamically when it is populated.

Please let me know how we can set the RowHeight of the list item dynamically.

```
var StatusList = new ListView
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            RowHeight = Constants.CategoryRowHeight + 60,
            BackgroundColor = Constants.BackgroundColor,
            ItemTemplate = GetDataTemplate()
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the HasUnevenRows property of ListView to True.

```
    var StatusList = new ListView
    {
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        HasUnevenRows = true,
        RowHeight = Constants.CategoryRowHeight + 60,
        BackgroundColor = Constants.BackgroundColor,
        ItemTemplate = GetDataTemplate()
    };
```

Comment: If i use HasUnEvenRows = true. The UI is breaking on IOS

Comment: can u share the screenshot?

Comment: Also please remove the RowHeight property as well.. because you have set the HasUnevenRows to true

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug on iOS which causes that the rows cannot have different heights. Setting `HasUnevenRows=true` only causes that you can set a custom height for ALL cells. If this bug ever gets fixes, I can inform you. But: this will work for UWP and Android, so you can use a different CellView for iOS instead